# Making my own monadic type based on list

Tags: haskell

I want to use Haskell to solve a financial combinatorial problem, the list monad seems to be a good fit for this.

Now, my problem with the list monad is its inability to give names to the values involved. I will try to exemplify:

```
loan = [1000*x | x <- [1..3]]
interest_rate = [0.005*x | x <- [4..10]]

calc = do                                                                                    
  l <- loan                                                                                  
  i <- interest_rate                                                                         
  return (l*i)
```

Running calc above gives me a list of numbers (`[20.0,25.0,30.0,35.0,40.0, ... ]`), but I can't tell what the loan and interest rate is used for each calculation.

I get lost here, my intuition tells me to create my own monadic type of, say `HelpfulNumber :: (String,[Double])` and somehow say that:

`>>=` and `return` should be `>>= . snd` and `return . snd`

Am I on the right course here, or is there a better way? I am feeling a bit lost to be honest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a record type to make your output clearer:

```
data Loan = Loan {final :: Double, 
                  rate  :: Double, 
                  loan  :: Integer, 
                  years :: Int}
   deriving Show

printloans :: [Loan] -> IO()
printloans = mapM_ print
```

Use `printloans loans` or `printloans loans'` at the ghci prompt.

Edit: I forgot to include the definition of `dp`. It's for rounding to a given number of decimal places:

```
dp :: Int -> Double -> Double
n `dp` a = (/ 10.0^n).fromInteger.round.(* 10.0^n) $ a
```

Here's a way using a list directly:

```
loans = [Loan {final = (2 `dp`) $ fromInteger amt*(1+ir)^yrs, 
               rate  = ir,
               loan  = amt,
               years = yrs}  
        | ir <- [0.005*x | x <- [4..10]],
          amt <- [1000*x | x <- [1..3]],
          yrs <- [1..4]
        ]
```

But if you like the monadic style, you can use:

```
loans' = do
  ir <- [0.005*x | x <- [4..10]]
  amt <- [1000*x | x <- [1..3]]
  yrs <- [1..4]
  return Loan {final = (2 `dp`) $ fromInteger amt*(1+ir)^yrs, 
               rate  = ir,
               loan  = amt,
               years = yrs}
```

which benefits from fewer commas, and it's easier to change the order of the `<-` lines to change the order of the answers.
You can add extras to your `Loan` record and calculate with them. 
You get output like this:

```
*Main> printloans loans'
Loan {final = 1020.0, rate = 2.0e-2, loan = 1000, years = 1}
Loan {final = 1040.4, rate = 2.0e-2, loan = 1000, years = 2}
Loan {final = 1061.21, rate = 2.0e-2, loan = 1000, years = 3}
Loan {final = 1082.43, rate = 2.0e-2, loan = 1000, years = 4}
Loan {final = 2040.0, rate = 2.0e-2, loan = 2000, years = 1}
Loan {final = 2080.8, rate = 2.0e-2, loan = 2000, years = 2}
...
...
```

EDIT:

You told me elsewhere you'd like output like `ir_5% yrs_3 amt_4000 tot_4360.5`. It's uglier, but here's a way of doing that sort of thing:

```
loans'' = do
  ir <- [0.005*x | x <- [4..10]]
  amt <- [1000*x | x <- [1..3]]
  yrs <- [1..4]
  let final = (2 `dp`) $ fromInteger amt*(1+ir)^yrs
  return $ "final_" ++ show final
        ++ ",  ir_" ++ show ((2 `dp`) $ ir*100.0)    -- rounded away a rounding error in 3.5% 
        ++ "%,  amt_" ++ show amt 
        ++ ",  yrs_" ++ show yrs
```

When you do `mapM_ putStrLn loans''` you get output like

```
final_1020.0,  ir_2.0%,  amt_1000,  yrs_1
final_1040.4,  ir_2.0%,  amt_1000,  yrs_2
final_1061.21,  ir_2.0%,  amt_1000,  yrs_3
final_1082.43,  ir_2.0%,  amt_1000,  yrs_4
final_2040.0,  ir_2.0%,  amt_2000,  yrs_1
....
```

but I think the record type is **much** nicer - its output is easier to read and there's less messing about with strings.

Comment: I'd probably define a `LoanInput` record that doesn't include `final`, so then you can define a `loanInputs` variable as just a list of your inputs, and keep the calculation of the output in a separate function.  Then create your `Loan` record as `{LoanInput, Double}`.  That'll make it easier to map your input list to different calculation options, and decouple the calculation function(s) from the creation of the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just make two helper functions?

```
getName (loan, rate) = "loan="++loan++"&rate="++rate

getAnswer (loan, rate) = loan*rate
```

Then use a list comprehension

```
loans = [1000*x | x <- [1..3]]
interest_rates = [0.005*x | x <- [4..10]]

input_tuples = [(l, i) | l<-loans, i<-interest_rates]]

answers = [(getName t, getAnswer t) | t<-input_tuples]]
```

No monads necessary, not even list monad.

Comment: I think you are right, I could first compute every combination and store them in a tuple. From there I can actually go about and do the computations I want to do. No need to complicate things, thanks I will try this!

Comment: But also it needs to be pointed out that the list comprehension is really the list monad, no? :) at least in a computational point of view. I don't know how it is implemented under the hood.

Comment: @Magnus, sure, however beginning Haskellers are normally introduced to list comprehensions long before monads, so the list comprehension is more accessible to beginners who find monad syntax intimidating.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're looking for here, because how would you give names to interest rates?

But you can of course store the interest rate along with the final result:

```
calc = do                                                                                    
  l <- loan                                                                                  
  i <- interest_rate                                                                         
  return (i, l*i)
-- Yields: [(0.02, 20.0), (0.025, 25.0), ...]
```

Comment: Actually i would prefer not to get into the naming part since it is an uninteresting part of the problem. But an example could be this function `let name_ir x = "ir_"++(show.(100*) $ x)++"%"`.

Comment: My real problem is that there will be 10 or so parameters, each being a list of possible values, in the end I would like to see which values yielded what end result.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to see in the end? Do you mean something like `ir_5% yrs_3 amt_4000 tot_4360.5`, where interest rate `ir_` and years `yrs_` are examples of the parameters you mention?

Comment: If you've got functions "GetName" for every parameter, you can modify the dflemstr's return statement to `return ((GetLoanName l) ++ (GetInterestName i), l*i)`, and just follow that pattern

Comment: @AndrewC Yes, that is what I see in the end. Then I would have the solution for my multivariable problem.

Comment: @AndrewC I would love to reformulate the question to be more general. I made a concrete example out of simplicity.